# How to show image in string in runtime using MVC c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I get image bytes from database and want render thias in image src in string format.How to render that image in runtime?
This is my scenario.

```
public string GetTickerData()
        {
            string strData = "";
            string strImageData = "";
            string strDateFormat = "";
            byte[] imgdata;
            int s = 0;
            strImageData = "";                                   
            strImageData += "<img runat=\"server\" src=\"TickerImage.ashx?ColName=" + dtTickerData.Columns[j].ColumnName + "&ID=" + s + "\"  />";
            ViewData["Data"]=strImageData ;
        }
```

Image.cshtml

```
@{
  var t= @ViewData["Data"];
}
<div>
 <label class="footerLabel" style="text-align:center">@ViewData["Data"]</label>
</div>
```

Image handler

```
public class TickerImage : IHttpHandler
    {
        string ColumnName = string.Empty;
        int RowID = 0;
        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            if (context.Request.QueryString["ColName"] != null)
                ColumnName = context.Request.QueryString["ColName"];

            if (context.Request.QueryString["ID"] != null)
                RowID = Convert.ToInt32(context.Request.QueryString["ID"]);
            else
                RowID = 0;

            DataTable dtTemp = (DataTable)context.Session["TickerData"];

            if (!(dtTemp.Rows[RowID][ColumnName] is DBNull))
                context.Response.BinaryWrite((byte[])dtTemp.Rows[RowID][ColumnName]);
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks fine, but you're missing a closing quote.

```
strImageData += "<img src=\"" + imgg + "  />";
```

This should be:

```
strImageData += "<img src=\"" + imgg + "\"  />";
```

Comment: No difference at all.